# How to avoid firebase automatically log out current account and sign in new account after admin's account create a new account for members in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

```
void registerGuardianAndSenior(String text) async {
    // Show loading circle
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
    // Make sure pw match
    if (passwordController.text != comfirmPswdController.text) {
      if (context.mounted) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        displayMessageToUser("Passwords don't match!", context);
      }
    } else {
      try {
        if (text == "Guardian") {
          UserCredential? userCredential `your text`= await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: emailController.text,
                  password: passwordController.text);
          createUserDocument(userCredential);
        } else {
          FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
          User? currentUser = auth.currentUser;

          if (currentUser != null) {
            String currentUserEmail = currentUser.email!;
            String currentUserName = usernameController.text;
            String currentUserPhone = phoneNumController.text;
            String currentUserGender = genderDropdownValue!;

            // Sign out the current user
            // await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
            // Create the senior document
            await createSeniorDocument(
              emailController.text,
              currentUserEmail,
              currentUserName,
              currentUserPhone,
              currentUserGender,
            );
            FirebaseApp secondaryApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
              name: 'SecondaryApp',
              options: Firebase.app().options,
            );

            try {
              UserCredential credential =
                  await FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: secondaryApp)
                      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: currentUserEmail,
                password: passwordController.text,
              );
            } catch (e) {
              print('An error occured. Please try again.');
            }

// after creating the account, delete the secondary app as below:
            await secondaryApp.delete();
          }
        }
        if (context.mounted) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (context.mounted) {
          // Pop loading circle
          Navigator.pop(context);
          // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
          displayMessageToUser(e.code, context);
        }
      }
    }
    // Try creating the user
  }

  Future<void> createUserDocument(UserCredential? userCredential) async {
    if (userCredential != null && userCredential.user != null) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(userCredential.user!.email)
          .set({
        'email': userCredential.user!.email,
        'username': usernameController.text,
        'phone number': phoneNumController.text,
        'gender': genderDropdownValue,
        // 'seniorUID': null, // Use null instead of Null
        // 'character': characterDropdownValue,
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> createSeniorDocument(
    String seniorEmail,
    String guardianEmail,
    String userName,
    String phone,
    String gender,
  ) async {
    try {
      // Create the senior's document
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("SeniorCitizens")
          .doc(seniorEmail)
          .set({
        'email': seniorEmail,
        'username': userName,
        'phone number': phone,
        'gender': gender,
        'guardianID': guardianEmail,
      });
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: seniorEmail, password: passwordController.text);
    } catch (e) {
      print("***Error creating senior document: $e");
    }
  }`
```

I am using flutter and firebase for this current app

and hope that my current admin account can keep sign in after creating a new account for other members. The issue I am facing is the new user will automatically sign in and replace the admin account I signed in before. Your help and advises will be appreciated thank you for your comments.

Comment: The Firebase SDKs can (by design) only have one current user. They are not made to perform administrative apps like the one you are trying to perform. While there is a trick to creating the new user in a separate `FirebaseApp` instance, the better approach is to create the new user in a trusted server environment, using the Admin SDK.